# Updating comments and state from the same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a small expense tracking app using Rails 4.1. When a user submits the expense request, it's state is marked as pending by default. The admin has to approve the request. I'm using state_machine gem to do this.

I just added comment functionality using acts_as_commentable gem, which works fine on its own. I wanted to combine the approval drop down and the comment box in the same form and used the following code in the expense show page:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= form_for [@expense, Comment.new] do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :state %><br />
        <%= f.collection_select :state, @expense.state_transitions, :event, :human_to_name, :include_blank => @expense.human_state_name, class: "form-control" %>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :comment %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :comment, class: "form-control" %>
       </div>
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

The problem is I get the "NoMethodError in Expenses#show - undefined method `state' for #". Is there a way I can update both the approval status and comment in one go?

The updated show page with nested attributes:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= nested_form_for (@expense) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :state %><br />
        <%= f.collection_select :state, @expense.state_transitions, :event, :human_to_name, :include_blank => @expense.human_state_name, class: "form-control" %>
       </div>
         <%= f.fields_for :comments do |comment| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= comment.label :comment%>
            <%= comment.text_area :comment, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) are your friend. They are so easy to implement I'd recommend avoiding `acts_as_commentable` to remove an unnecessary dependency and so you understand what's going on.

Use them like this:

```
# expense.rb
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments # << if polymorphic add `, as: :commentable`
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end

# expenses_controller.rb
def new
  @expense = Expense.new
  @expense.comments.build
end

# expenses/new.html.haml
= form_for(@expense) do |f|
  - # expense inputs...
  = f.nested_fields_for(:comments) do |comment|
    = comment.text_area(:body)
  = f.submit
```

There are many options, so check [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) for more details (they're quite good).

Comment: I took your advice and used nested attributes. The show page loads now but I don't see the comment text area in the page. I have updated the question with the new code.

Comment: The comment fields will only show when a comment is built onto the expense object. Did you add this in your controller? `@expense.comments.build`